# Usage of have: "Could you please explain why have these invoices been cancelled" is correct?

Tags: word-order

Is it correct sentence:
"Could you please explain why **have** these invoices been cancelled?"
Or 
"Could you please explain why these invoices **have** been cancelled?"
I heard that that have should always stay before noun.

Comment: related: [“Where am I?” vs. “Where I am?”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/93004/where-am-i-vs-where-i-am)

Comment: related: [asking a question with “have”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/114294/asking-a-question-with-have)

Comment: Consider a shorter, simpler example based on the same construction:  *"Explain why is it so"* vs *"Explain why it is so"*. The former would only normally occur in casual speech.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's either:

> *Why **have** these invoices been cancelled?*

or

> *Would you please explain why these invoices **have** been cancelled?*

The first is a direct question: ***Why has this been done?***
The second is an indirect question: ***Please explain why this has been done.***

Answer (score 0):

[Edited to make more concise]

The trick to understanding where to place "have" is to understand the use of the word "why."  If used to introduce a question, you would want to put the have first: "Why have these invoices been cancelled?"  If used to introduce a noun clause, you want to put the have next to the word been: "why these invoices have been cancelled."  In your original sentence, you are using why as a noun clause, so you should phrase it as: "Could you please explain why these invoices have been cancelled?"

That noted, as @TrevorD mentioned, "Why have these invoices been cancelled?" is a more direct, and often preferred, version in written English.